# Android Frame Animation

Tags: android

I would like to know if it is possible to remove one of the frames I added using addFrame in Android?

Thanks

Kelvin

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to removing frames in an [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html), then no (not directly), though I'm guessing there's probably a workaround. If you describe your use case further I'd be glad to elaborate.

For reference, [here's the source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.java) for the `AnimationDrawable` class.